# when to use the SPSite and SPweb from context or when to create a new instance?

Tags: 2010

I already read the document about disposal about 10 times in the last 3 years.  But my question is different.

Why wouldnt I always use 
SPContext.Site and .Web

instead of always creating an object instance?
using (SPSite site =

I suppose it has to do with the kind of operations you are going to do with the objects? As far as I know creating an instance its more resource intensive, so the more I use the Context object the better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also create new `SPSite` and `SPWeb` inside of `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`. SPSite object permissions are determined when they are created, so `SPContext.Current.Site` will already have the permissions of the current user even if you get the reference within RWEP.

Comment: Yep, forgot about that one. :)

Comment: can you check this blog and let me know additional comments? http://levalencia.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/spsite-and-spweb-instantiation-vs-spcontext-spsite-and-spcontext-spweb/

Comment: Add the following to bullet 4 in your blog: When you need to access data from another Site collection/site than the current.

Answer (score 4):

I create a new SPSite or SPWeb instance when I don't have a SPContext (console app, powershell, unit test, etc) or I need to get data from a different SPSite and SPWeb than the one I'm currently accessing.

Comment: good point. I am actually seeing the code in the project I am and the developer uses new SpSite and New SpObject all over the place, like 20 times per page.

Comment: Wow, yea, if you turn on the developer dashboard, you should be able to see all of the sprequest objects and how much time they are taking up on page load.

Comment: can you check this blog and let me know additional comments? http://levalencia.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/spsite-and-spweb-instantiation-vs-spcontext-spsite-and-spcontext-spweb/